# php database, jquery dynamic content load

Tags: php, jquery, database, dynamic

I would like to achieve such an effect, except that when you click on the picture (link) jquery script sends a GET to the same file from the fact that with another ID. I mean the dynamic reload the page without refreshing the addition of a nice effect in the attached link.

my code :

```
<script>
$('a.menu').click(function(){
    $('.content').html('');

})
</script>

<div class="content" id="page_effect" style="padding:0px; display:none;">
<div class="separator" style="margin: -17px auto;"></div>
<span class="choose-product"> Wybierz Produkt</span>

<p>
<?php
$kat=$_GET['kat'];
$co_ile_strona=9;
//----------------

$dopisz="";

if (is_numeric($kat)) {

$dopisz=" WHERE kat_id='".$kat."'";
$wyk=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kategorie WHERE kat='".$kat."'");
while($ww=mysql_fetch_array($wyk)) {
$dopisz.=" OR kat_id='".$ww['id']."'";
}

}

$sile=false;
$wyk=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produkty ".$dopisz."");
if ($ile=mysql_num_rows($wyk)) {

if (!$sile) { 

$nazwa = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kategorie WHERE id='".$_GET['kat']."'"));
if(strlen($nazwa['nazwa']) > 0)
$nazwa = $nazwa['nazwa'];
?>


<div style="text-align: center; width: 80%;margin: 0 auto;margin-top: 39px;">
    <a href="produkt.html"><div class="product-box">
        <img src="images/picasso0.png" alt="Product"/>
        <span class="product-title"><?=$nazwa?></span>
    </div>
    </a>

    <?
$sile=true;
}
if (!$_GET['strona']) $strona=1; else $strona=$_GET['strona'];
$start=($strona*$co_ile_strona)-$co_ile_strona;
mysql_data_seek($wyk,$start);
$licz=0;

while(($ww=mysql_fetch_object($wyk)) && $licz<$co_ile_strona) { $licz++;
?>
   <a href="<?=strtolower(seo($ww->nazwa))?>-<?=$ww->id?>p.html"><div class="product-box">
        <img src="produkty/front/<?=$ww->front?>" alt="<?=$ww->nazwa?>"/>
        <div class="name2"><span><?=$ww->nazwa?> </span></div>
    </div>
    </a> 
<?
}
} else echo "<span style='color: #ff0000; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold;'>Przepraszamy, ale nie znaleziono produktów pasujących do tego zapytania</span>";
?>

</div>
    <div class="menu-bottom" style="text-align:center;">
        <span style="position: relative;top: 25px;display: inline-flex;margin-bottom: 20px;">Wybierz serię:
        <ul>
<?php
$zapas=$_GET['kat'];
$wyk=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kategorie WHERE kat='0' and wid='1' ORDER BY poz ASC");
while($ww=mysql_fetch_object($wyk)) {
?> <!--<?/*=$ww->nazwa?>-<?=$ww->id*/?>k.html*/-->
<li> <a href="<?=$ww->id;?>" class="menu" title="<?=$ww->nazwa?>"><? if($_GET['kat']==$ww->id) echo "<span style='color: #000;'>".$ww->nazwa.""; else echo $ww->nazwa?></a></li>
<? } ?>
        </ul>
    </span>
    </div>

    <!-- end .content --></div>
```

link : [Click here](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/11/beautiful-apple-gallery-slideshow/demo.html)

Comment: Take a look at the `get()` or `post()` jQuery functions. Side notes: do not use mysql_, use mysqli_ or PDO instead; your naming convention is terrible. Try to not mix English and Polish, I'd recommend using English.

Comment: Thanks Adnrzej for your resposne, I only must modifiy this code, I always use english variable :)
Dzięki Andrzej za odpowiedź. Zawsze używam angielskich nazw zmiennych. Wiem jak używać posta i Geta w js, ale zawsze to się wiąże, z przeładowaniem strony :(

Comment: Let's better use English :) `get()` or `post()` jQuery functions do not cause page reload. Let me prepare an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you should send an AJAX request to the page that is responsible for handling the database tasks. You can use `get()` or `post()` function which is a shorthand of AJAX function as stated in [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

I've prepared a simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vKWF3/) demonstrating how the task can be achieved (please note the `event.preventDefault()` [call](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(e){
      var URL = '';
      $.get(URL,function(data){
      console.log("Status: " + status);
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
});
```

Hope that helps.